# Import cucumber results to Jira/Xray due the curl

Tags: javascript, cucumber, jira, jira-xray

For import results I use curl

```
var util = require('util');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var command = 'curl -u username:password -F info=@cypress/support/xray-json/issue-data.json -F result=@cypress/cucumber-json/test-results.json https://project.atlassian.net/rest/raven/1.0/import/execution/cucumber'

child = exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);

    if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }

});
```

but also receive the error below

[image]

Comment: Are you using Xray on Jira cloud or Xray for Jira server/datacenter?

Comment: Hi @Sérgio, how can I find out if I'm using Xray on Jira cloud or Xray for Jira server?

Comment: You can ask your Jira administrator. Usually cloud domain end up in .atlassian.net but some organizations use custom domains for their cloud solutions. Also usually server/datacenter is hosted locally, so it has an internal domain/URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Xray on Jira Cloud...
An example of doing this request with `curl` in a bash script would be something like:

```
# the followin URL corresponds Xray Cloud domain that provides multiple endpoints, for authenticating and other operations
BASE_URL=https://xray.cloud.getxray.app
token=$(curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data @"cloud_auth.json" "$BASE_URL/api/v2/authenticate"| tr -d '"')
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"  --data @"report.json" "$BASE_URL/api/v2/import/execution/cucumber"
```

In the previous script, we can see two endpoints being used: one for authentication and another for importing the results:

- https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate
- https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution/cucumber

These endpoints are from Xray cloud itself; not from Jira. They are not Jira instance specific; they don't change.

The cloud_auth.json used above, has contents such as this:

```
{ "client_id": "DA2258616A594400000000","client_secret": "5bae1aa5b49e5d263781da54ba0000000000000000000" }
```

You need to obtain the client_id and client_secret from an API key configured in Xray global settings.
[image]

In general,

- you need to obtain a token, by doing an authentication request with a client id and client secret that you may find in your Xray administration settings, under API keys (you cannot use basic authentication nor the Jira credentials). The authentication endpoint is https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/authenticate
- then you can make the HTTP Post request to Xray Cloud, using that token; however, the correct API endpoint is https://xray.cloud.getxray.app/api/v2/import/execution/cucumber

Note that the previous endpoint is the "standard", or in other words the most simple one to use. There is also another endpoint, called the multipart. The syntax is different. You may see here one [example](https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/tree/main/use_cases/import_automation_results#xray-cloud-1) for it.

You may find more info about the Xray Cloud REST API endpoints [here](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/REST+API) (currently the site seems to having some load).

Comment: could you please explain more
what is base_url and what data should be in cloud_auth.json

Comment: can i use instead of @"clod_auth.json" credentials username:jira_token ?

Comment: no, you cannot use Jira related authentication. you have to use the credentials and the authentication mechanism from Xray, and not from Jira itself. I will update the answer with feedback of your first question

Comment: I've updated the answer above

Comment: could you please explain where i can change the title 
`Execution results [1649934355283]` - now
i'm using xray-code-snippets

Comment: You can't, if you use the standard endpoint as shown above. You'll have to use the multipart endpoint instead, which has a different format. You can see here an example where an auxiliary JSON is used to customize via the Summary field: https://github.com/Xray-App/xray-code-snippets/blob/main/use_cases/import_automation_results/js/import_results_cucumber_multipart_axios_cloud.js